# Change body opacity via javascript

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

I have a slider who changes the opacity for my website

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        $('#slider').slider({ 
        min: 0, 
        max: 1, 
        step: 0.01, 
        value: 1,
        orientation: "vertical",
             slide: function(e,ui){
$('body').css('opacity', ui.value)
             }                
        })
    });
</script>
```

But i want to not change opacity for 2 or 3 classes inside my body. Thanks.

LE : In the same time i want to reduce the level of opacity of some elemnts, instead of them i want a black masque. So on the entire site only .the_window and .the_trigger to be visible and the backround black. Exemple : catalog-online.ro/test/

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.opacity = "0";
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS [`opacity`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency) will apply to descendant elements. Since you are changing the `<body>` opacity it will affect the entire page. You will have to select other elements on the page and change the opacity on those, avoiding the classes that you want to not change opacity for.

**Edit:** Here is a very [**simple demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pr78v/) that might help:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">Lorem ipsum, my opactiy is not affected</div>
<p>My opactiy is affected</p>
<div id="lightbox"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#lightbox {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:.6;

}

#main {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
}

p {
    color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but background-image from body still aperead and i want to change opacity include background-image

Comment: Please update your question with a demo or the full HTML, CSS and JavaScript of the problem then, otherwise it will be difficult to help.

Comment: @andyb what about z-Index property, if we set it to a higher value than body and make inner elements absolute then it may work. what do you say?

Comment: It might be possible but a demo of the code in question would be required to work with first. Otherwise we are just guessing!

Comment: In the same time i want to reduce the level of opacity of some elemnts, instead of them i want a black masque. So on the entire site only .the_window and .the_trigger to be visible and the backround black. Exemple : http://catalog-online.ro/test/

Comment: Nobody can`t help me ? Maybe an ideea for what i want.

Comment: The only approach that might work is to absolutely position the elements that you do not want to change opacity on. They will also need to exist in the DOM outside the lightbox `<div>` which you will be applying opacity to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a jquery guy but you can try something like this in slide function:

```
slide: function(e,ui){
   $('body').css('opacity', ui.value);
   $('#element_1_ID').css('opacity', 1);
   $('#element_2_ID').css('opacity', 1);
}
```

Replace element_1_ID and element_2_ID with the ID of those elements on which you do not want to apply opacity. Hopefully it may work, otherwise another option might be to set opacity of individual elements. Setting some to 0 and some to 1.

Comment: I have tried with this  $('#element_1_ID').css('opacity', 1); but is not working.